# Changing Map Coordinate System Changes in ArcGIS Pro Changes Azimuth

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, wgs84, web-mercator, postgis-2.4

I am trying to create a label that will overlay a line in ArcGIS Pro, the layer is coming from a PostGIS database. The underlying materialized view for the label/symbol overlay is something like this:

```
SELECT
   label,
   degrees(public.ST_Azimuth(public.ST_StartPoint(public.ST_UNION(geom)), public.ST_EndPoint(public.ST_UNION(geom)))) AS Azimuth,
   geom
FROM
   TABLE
```

In ArcGIS Pro the label overlays perfectly initially:
[image: Looks perfect to start]

Then I go to the Table of Contents and under map properties change the map's coordinate system from lat/long to Web Mercator Auxiliary Sphere:

[image: Change to Web Mercator Aux Sphere]

Then ArcGIS Pro puts the label at the wrong angle and at an odd offset:

[image: Now its wrong]

This phenomenon is localized to certain areas of the globe. It seems to me that the offset makes no sense. I have tried projecting the line geometry into Web Mercator (srid: 3857) using `ST_transform` and getting the azimuth using `ST_Azimuth` and the azimuth angle changes but still isn't right.

Shouldn't ArcGIS Pro at the very least reproject the the point on the line and shouldnt it match the azimuth if I calculate it in Web Mercator in PostGIS?

Comment: Short answer: No. Azimuth in 4326 means nothing (unless calculated with geodetic functions, in which case it wouldn't look right). I doubt the Web Mercator azimuth is true either (because of Auxiliary Sphere, if nothing else). If you [Edit] the question to include one or two specific line segments, then there's an opportunity to do math.

Comment: The GeoJSON for the line in question is: ` {"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-7727984.57838143,6200249.38476172],[-7594441.69836957,6297632.81487629]]}` The thing is that the `ST_Azimuth` mostly works perfectly, its only the odd line that has this issue.

Comment: Is your data concentrated in a certain location? If so, I would recommend using a local projected coordinate system instead, like State Plane.

Comment: no my data spans the globe. I actually solved this by projecting in PostGIS first. For whatever reason having Arc retroject caused issues...